# Sum of a predefined List F#

Tags: list, recursion, f#, sum, blackjack

I am a beginner F# learner, currently trying some Lists actions within a BlackJack F# implementation.

I am trying to sum the elements of a list which I created as follows:

```
let cardsvalue (k: Cards): List<int> =
    match k with
    |Ace ->  [1;11]
    |Two -> [2] 
    |Three -> [3]
    |Four -> [4]
    |Five -> [5]
    |Six -> [6]
    |Seven -> [7]
    |Eight -> [8]
    |Nine -> [9]
    |Ten | Jack | Queen | King -> [10]
```

`type Cards`  is just a union of the cards Two to Nine , Ten to King and Ace.

So I need some kind of recursive function CardPoints which simply adds items from `cardsvalue` for example `[Two; Three] = [5]` or `[Ace; Ace; Ace] = [3; 13; 23; 33]` meaning all possible values of the Ace. I have tried several common ways of getting the sum but I always end up with type mismatch or not supporting operator error. For example

```
let rec CardPoints (cp: List<Cards>): List<int> =   
   match cp with
   | head :: tail -> head + CardPoints tail
   | [] -> 0
```

which is not accepting the + opperator.

I would love to see a possible implementation of this problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: you're tryinh to add a number to a list of numbers

Comment: you're very close, so to tell you would spoil it.

Comment: Do you mind sharing it? How would it look like

Comment: the problem here is that this group gets posts from people who want you to do their homework....so people are very nervous about explicitly giving you the whole answer.

Comment: Yeah I can see that. I guess people are happier leaving a question unanswered

Comment: Is it homework? or just something you are trying to do?

Comment: No, just getting to know more about this language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your answer is very close.
but you are trying to add a "Card" to a list of ints.
what you want to do is take each possible value of the card and add that to each possible value of the sum of the rest of the cards.

OK, I probably wouldn't do it it quite like this, but maybe this is the easiest answer to understand (assuming you understand list comprehensions).

Its also no quite perfect functionally, but I'll leave that to you to find out and fix.

```
let rec cardPoints (cp: List<Card>): List<int> =   
   match cp with
   | head :: tail -> 
        [ for val1 in cardsvalue head do
            for val2 in cardPoints tail do 
                val1 + val2 ]
   | [] -> [0]
```

Comment: Thanks! You might wanna edit `yield` to the `val1 + val2`.

Comment: I havent tested this, implicit yields are supported in F#, so in my head it works, it will give duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

> I am a beginner F# learner

Your code shows a nice systematic approach and you've already done most of the work to allow the type system (and intellisense) to help solve your problem.

```ml
let cardsvalue (k: Cards): List<int> =
```

A useful function with exactly the right type signature. Notice that it's greyed out. That means you are not using it.

```ml
let rec CardPoints (cp: List<Cards>): List<int> =
```

Also exactly right. You are giving as much help to the type system as possible which makes it almost certain that it will spot the exact point at which something is going wrong.

> I always end up with type mismatch or not supporting operator error. For example
>
> ```ml
>     | head :: tail -> head + CardPoints tail
> ```

Try using a binding to help figure this out:

```ml
    | head :: tail ->
        let tailPoints = CardPoints tail
        head + tailPoints
```

You can tell (by hovering over them) that `head` is a `Cards` and `tailPoints` is a `List<int>`. So you are trying to add a `Cards` to a `List<int>` and there is no such addition operation defined.

So you've honed this down to a smaller task: given a card (`head: Cards`), and given the points possible (`tailPoints: List<int>`) from the remaining cards, how can you find the points possible from all cards, which should be a `List<int>`? You will need to use your currently unused function `cardsvalue` and another small step and you are there.

Comment: can you please show how it's done, I cant get it to work. And one last question - how would you implement the condition for the Ace to not score over 21, for example `[Ace;Ace;Ace]` should be just 13 (1+1+11) and `[Ace; Five; Ace]` would be 17.

Comment: I personally would define my own `type Points = Hard of int | Soft of int*int` and than use something like this 
    `match cp with
    | Hard x -> Hard x
    | Soft(x,y) -> if y > 21 then Hard x else Soft(x,y)`

but this would require me to rewrite everything all over again. Can you show me how it will look like if we use third function for example `let CalScore (cp: List<Cards>): int =`

Comment: @BillyFitt I would get the original problem and attempt to work before trying extensions or alternatives. You need to create a function which given a `Cards` and an `int list` of possible scores from remaining cards, will return the `int list` of overall possible scores. You already have a function which gives you possible scores from the cards. That can be used to simplify the problem, eliminating `Cards`, so in the remaining step you only have to work with ints.

Comment: The original problem is what I asked in my post. Could you show me how to do it , I mean  the use of my currently unused function cardsvalue and the other small step - I somehow still couldnt get it working

Comment: Well your cardsValue function gives you the possible values of the first card (an `int list`), and recursion gives you `tailPoints`, another `int list`. So the problem is reduced to: given two `int list`s, find all possible sums. To do this, you may find it helpful to use the functions `List.map` and `List.concat`, or alternatively to use the "yield" syntax to construct a list `[ for x in someSequence do yield f(x) ]`.

Comment: Here are 3 solutions to the last problem: `let allSums(l1:int list, l2:int list) = [ for x in l1 do for y in l2 do yield x + y ]`. `let allSums2(l1:int list, l2:int list) = l1 |> List.map (fun x -> l2 |> List.map (fun y -> x + y)) |> List.concat`. `let rec allSums3(l1:int list, l2:int list) = match l1 with | [] -> [] | h :: t -> (l2 |> List.map (fun y -> y + h)) @ allSums3(t, l2)`.